# How to connect mysql 8.0 version with python and use them

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

1. I am not able to connect MySql8.0.35 with python3    i am using vscode.

I tried using Mysql connector but it showed the error mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Comment: Which mysql.connector version? It doesn't' appear to be up to date with the server.